# How can I place another button on top of four buttons in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I am trying to achieve this format in my android application. The format is the following:-

[[image: Initial Design]]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="com.example.nero.application.MainControl">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#f000"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#f000"
        android:background="@color/red" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#f000"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#f000"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I always use LinearLayout in my work because it's easy to understand and works in stacks. Whereas, RelativeLayout is a bit complicated for me (personally). This is what I've currently done and I was also trying to add a FrameLayout on top of everything for the final button to be displayed but I am not able to get the exact positioning in place.

Another issue I am trying to avoid is making this design universal for different screen size.

Any help would be grateful, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code after you added the FrameLayout ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I've removed that FrameLayout code because when I place my LinearLayout in my FrameLayout, all the buttons are placed on top of each other on top.

Comment: Here what you should do: Take this whole code AS IT IS (Keeping even the outer LinearLayout) and place it inside a FrameLayout, make sure nothing changes visually. Then add a button inside your FrameLayout but outside the LinearLayout with the Gravity Center for the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#f000"
                android:background="@color/red"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#f000"
                android:background="@color/red" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#f000"
                android:background="@color/red"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#f000"
                android:background="@color/red"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:background="#54e"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Just replace the `View` element with whichever type you need and add a background of shape oval to make to round.

Comment: Works like a charm and makes sense too
Thanks